# Big buttons on big screens - dpi vs absolute resolution mixup

Tags: android

I have just realised I have been under the wrong impression about the whole mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi issue. I had the idea that on a big 10 inch tablet, the OS will naturally use the image in the xhdpi directory and on a small phone the OS will select the one in the mdpi directory... but after some experimentation I've realised that the different directories are for different *pixels per inch* and independent of the the actual total number of pixels. But this is a real problem, because now I am having trouble arranging to have the largest images being used for the largest absolute number of pixels. Can this be done without stretching/shrinking the bitmaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I was tripped up because all the XML examples I ever saw seemed to use mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi so I assumed that those were the only ways that existed to specify the characteristics of your screen. But I have just seen that you can use small/medium/large and other things too - described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#SmallestScreenWidthQualifier).